# Fix scrolling issues with liquid layout image 100% width and height?

Tags: css, scroll, fluid-layout

I am using a liquid layout on my site. The background is a an image ( slideshow ) and it works how I want. The photo stretches and resizes with the size of the browser.

However, I just noticed that when I move my browser window as thin or narrow as it goes, the image is still there but when I scroll to the right the image cuts off into the background. But full size works fine.

basically I want it to be 100% width and height at all times and never scroll horizontally or ever exposing the body.

Please let me know what else you need to know to help. Here is the html and css. thanks

```
#revolver {
 background-color:#ccc;
 width:100%;
 min-height:100%;
 z-index:10001;
}

.revolver-slide {
 width:100%;
 min-height:100%;
 background-position:center center;
 -webkit-background-size:cover;
 -moz-background-size:cover;
 -o-background-size:cover;
 background-size:cover;
}
.revolver-slide img {
 width:100%;
 min-height:100%;
}
.page-section {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 margin:0px auto 0px auto;
}
html,body {
 height:100%;
}
<div class="page-section clear">
<!-- 100% width -->

        <div id="revolver">
            <div class="revolver-slide" style="background-image:url('<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/slides/slide-6.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="revolver-slide" style="background-image:url('<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/slides/slide-2.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="revolver-slide" style="background-image:url('<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/slides/slide-8.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="revolver-slide" style="background-image:url('<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/slides/slide-11.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="revolver-slide" style="background-image:url('<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/slides/slide-7.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="revolver-slide" style="background-image:url('<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/slides/slide-4.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="revolver-slide" style="background-image:url('<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/slides/slide-9.jpg');"></div>

        </div>


</div>
```

Comment: @Muhammad Umer Does this help? http://jsfiddle.net/AYEg3/

Comment: no where are the images

Comment: @Muhammad Umer not sure how to do that. :\

Comment: if you still have problem. Go to google find 4 big images and put their url here. keep clicking till you have huge picture with black background. And when you right click it should say 'copy image URl'

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I put `overflow-x:hidden` on my page-section div and presto